# Rails changes slave to slafe when scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, scaffolding

I'm trying to generate a scaffold named "slave". When I run the command `rails generate scaffold slave` rails changes some parts of the scaffold from slave to slafe. Affected, for instance, are the resource routes.

Why does this happen and how can I fix this problem?

I am using Rails 5.0.2 with JRuby on RubyMine.

Comment: AFAIK this is not default behaviour. Maybe the pluralization rules have been changed. What are the contents of `config/initializers/inflections.rb`?

Comment: Inflections are empty (except for default comments).

Comment: It could be that an evil hipster has added a politcally correct inflections.rb file that will result in "slaves" becoming "slafes" and more infamously "Users" becoming "Beings"...Probably not it though.

Comment: @omnikron sorry, I forgot to tag you.

Comment: @ColinHerzog I was being stupid and just looking at filenames – this is indeed the default behaviour of rails. Pluralization of english nouns is a total nightmare!

Comment: Thank you for posting this. It was driving me crazy. I have a model ending in '_drive' and I wound up with '_drife' everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of an incorrect inflection. Rails inflections take a one-size-fits-all approach that works in most cases but can often catch you out because of how weird English pluralization is. In your case, the plural 'slaves' is being correctly generated from your input 'slave', but during the route helper generation rails evidently needs a singular version of 'slaves' and settles on 'slafe' because of [this inflection rule](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/48b37f127fb44b787ae6c0710982d7949b14454f/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb#L39):

```
inflect.singular(/([^f])ves$/i, '\1fe')
```

To fix this simply add a rule of your own:

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.singular('slaves', 'slave')
end
```

...run the generator again and it works:

```
$ rake routes | grep slave
                       slaves GET      /slaves(.:format)                                                   slaves#index
                              POST     /slaves(.:format)                                                   slaves#create
                    new_slave GET      /slaves/new(.:format)                                               slaves#new
                   edit_slave GET      /slaves/:id/edit(.:format)                                          slaves#edit
                        slave GET      /slaves/:id(.:format)                                               slaves#show
                              PATCH    /slaves/:id(.:format)                                               slaves#update
                              PUT      /slaves/:id(.:format)                                               slaves#update
                              DELETE   /slaves/:id(.:format)                                               slaves#destroy
```

Incidentally, the exact opposite problem can be caused by [this rule](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/48b37f127fb44b787ae6c0710982d7949b14454f/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb#L22):

```
inflect.plural(/(?:([^f])fe|([lr])f)$/i, '\1\2ves')
```

...which causes problems with e.g `rails generate scaffold cafe` - everything that should be 'cafes' becomes 'caves'. Argh!

Answer (score 0):

As already said by @omnikron, you can try to force an "irregular" inflection at the file `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'slave', 'slaves'
end
```